# Can't get NLTK-Trainer to recognize/ work with scikit-learn classifiers

Tags: python, nltk, argparse

I've been using the (excellent) NLTK-Trainer in order to train a NaiveBayes classifier to classify snippets of text. I see that NLTK-Trainer also supports the scikit-learn algorithms, and I would like to use these in hopes of decreasing memory usage/ increasing accuracy.

However, when I try to specify one of the scikit-learn classifiers when I run train_classifier.py, it throws an error:

```
train_classifier.py: error: argument --classifier/--algorithm: invalid choice: 'sklearn.BernoulliNB' (choose from 'NaiveBayes', 'DecisionTree', 'Maxent', 'GIS', 'IIS', 'MEGAM', 'TADM')
```

I am running the 32-bit Anaconda distribution (2.20) of Python 3.4.3 on Windows 7. "pip freeze" gives me the following: NLTK 3.0.4, scikit-learn 0.16.1. I believe I am using the latest version of NLTK-Trainer (I downloaded it a month ago).

After doing some research, I have two theories into what is going wrong:
1. There is some sort of arg parse error that isn't passing the --classifier sklearn.BernoulliNB to train_classifer.py correctly. After I do a traceback on the error, it gives me this

`nltk_data\nltk-trainer-master\nltk-trainer-master\train_classifier.py in <module>()
    131 nltk_trainer.classification.args.add_sklearn_args(parser)
    132 
--> 133 args = parser.parse_args()
    134 
AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in parse_args(self, args, namespace)
   1726     # =====================================
   1727     def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
-> 1728         args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
   1729         if argv:
   1730             msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
1765         except ArgumentError:
   1766             err = _sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 1767             self.error(str(err))
   1768 
   1769     def _parse_known_args(self, arg_strings, namespace):`

2. My other hypothesis is that the scikit-learn files that were included with Anaconda are in a place where NLTK-Trainer can't find them. Per Jacob Perkins' recommendations here ([comment](http://streamhacker.com/2012/11/22/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-nltk-scikitlearn/#comment-1041386095)) I can run the 'from nltk.classify import scikitlearn' command without error. However, when I look further into the nltk-trainer/args.py code here ([code](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer/blob/master/nltk_trainer/classification/args.py)), I cannot run the code following the 'import command'. All of these lines throw errors.

`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn import ensemble, feature_selection, linear_model, naive_bayes,      neighbors, svm, tree`

This has been really frustrating, and I can't quite put my finger on why it isn't working. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you're not able to do `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer` or any of the other sklearn import commands, it means that the scikit-learn library is not importable. This may be an issue with Anaconda, but maybe you can do `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is just code that takes your commandline arguments, and parses them.  It does not use or act on those arguments. That's done by following code.  The parser is just the gatekeeper, making sure that your inputs look correct.

I'm not familiar with `NLTK-Trainer`, but I can see what it's parser is doing.

From the error message it is clear that your argument, 'sklearn.BernoulliNB' is getting through.  But the `--classifier` argument was set up to only accept one of the strings in the `choices` list.  `['NaiveBayes', 'DecisionTree',...]`.  It doesn't accept just any name or module reference.

It is likely that the program takes an accepted name and maps it onto some other function, module or parameter.

Try calling this code with `-h` or `--help`, to see what arguments it acceepts.  And go to the program documentation to see what it says about the input.  Maybe there is some other way of specifying the alternative algorithms.  The `--classifier` is clearly setup to accept only a predefined set of value.

Comment: You are right that the options it gives are the defaults, but after looking at the nltk-trainer args.py file, it looks like it attempts to find a working scikit-learn library, and if it does, it adds the additional sk.learn options. There is 'def' code to add sklearn args, but ony if it finds scikit-learn. The link to the args.py file is in the original question if you would like to see all of it.

Comment: OK, choices lists like that can be dynamic, populated from the environment.  In which the problem is up stream, such as with the importing.